# how to build an efficient ItemBasedRecommender in Mahout?

Tags: mahout

I am building an Item Based Recommender System for 10 millions users who
rate categories over 20 possible categories (news categories like politic,
sport etc...)
I would like for each one of them to be recommended at least another
category which they don't know (no rating).

I runned a GenericUserBasedRecommender and asked for recommendations for
each user but It looks extremely long: maybe 1000 user proceeded per minute.
My questions are:

1- Can I run this same GenericUserBasedRecommender on hadoop and would it
really be faster? I saw and run an ItemBasedRecommender with command line on
a cluster, but I would rather run a User Based one.

1,5 - I saw many users not having a single recommendations. What is the alogrithm criterium to determine if a user get a recommendation? I thought It could be that the user who don't get recommendations are the one who only give a single rating, but I don't understand why.

2- Is there another smarter way to deal with my problem? Maybe some clustering
solution instead of recommendation? I don't exactly see how.

3- Finally, am I right when I say that the algorithms who have no command line
are not to be used with hadoop?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sometimes you won't get recommendations for certain items or users because there are few items over which they overlap. It could also be a case where the user data may be 'enough', but his behaviour/use patterns are very unique and/or disagreement with popular trends in the data.
2. You could perhaps try LogLikelihood or Tanimoto based ItemSimilarity.
3. Another thing you could look into is a Matrix Factorization based model. You could use the ALSWR Factorizer to generate recommendations. this method decomposes the original User-Item matrix, to a User-Feature, Item-Feature and Diagonal matrix,--> then reduces the dimensionality-->and then recronstructs the matrix which is closest to the original matrix with same rank. You might lose some data this method, but the missing values in the user-item matrix are imputed and you get estimate preference/recommendation values.
4. If you have the features and not just implicit ratings, you could probably experiment with clustering techniques, perhaps start with Hierarchical Clustering.
5. I did not quite get your last question.